How to check the output of pandas add() on large dataframes is correct?
I have 2 different dataframes. I want to add the each column of the second dataframe to each column of the first dataframe.
Sample data from first data frame
Date,DIVA,DIVB,DIVC,DIVD,DIVE,DIVF,DIVG,DIVH,DIVI,DIVJ,DIVK
2005-01-31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2005-02-28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2005-03-31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2005-04-30,0.0252046981557362,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2005-05-31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.00368753982464696,0,0.9967285943635,0.000786703640551191,0.204685336342504
2005-06-30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2005-07-31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2005-08-31,0,0,0,0.136626379400946,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2005-09-30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Sample data from second data frame
Date,COMPA,COMPB,COMPC,COMD,COMPE,COMPF,COMPG,COMPH,COMPI,COMPJ,COMPK
2005-01-31,1.29323576655363,4.9,2.38,7.65,2.80721171010353,0.517102785650544,0.55560896579964,0.4575,30.983401749063,0.15,7.1747278243798
2005-02-28,1.47054571738345,5.5,3.07,10.1,2.92068595927116,0.594265179616914,0.655293838077613,0.582350839585566,34.9927719551861,0.1415,7.98698951933502
2005-03-31,1.54651567506665,5.9,3.45,9,2.88222621184919,0.527861494989074,0.614182623195906,0.563734290843806,33.9408161727505,0.06,7.03287870795971
2005-04-30,1.4886952764977,5.65,3.5,8.2,2.83434922911437,0.503747063256048,0.619351447109741,0.537827178200071,33.8961693548387,0.098,6.58842165898618
2005-05-31,1.48708232252581,5.49,3.5,7.99,2.85385704175513,0.521946828395871,0.581911511859291,0.549893842887473,34.8308041010749,0.0845,6.94137021231385
2005-06-30,1.47725089511833,5.35,3.4,7.26574098332023,2.9020979020979,0.544446660204349,0.57480965816944,0.48076923076923,36.8166972316828,0.0745,6.67190638372195
2005-07-31,1.4781028275838,6.5,3.9,8.41983852364475,3.20890566565307,0.617541794589494,0.604174742701883,0.601167383174303,41.4141414141414,0.085,7.16507636922862
2005-08-31,1.45326897762176,9,5.65,8.30188679245283,3.77435321374662,0.641234277209302,0.660325801366264,0.596763435953241,48.6883720930233,0.082,7.45941202281703
2005-09-30,1.43183014563959,10.2,6.45,9.79119143709423,5.23349719101123,0.711875016669591,0.666832754948437,0.725421348314606,57.6943323390068,0.0875,7.94841200210563

I read both dataframes in a pandas dataframe. I applied the following line of code
total_returns = market_df.add(dividends_df, axis=1, fill_value=0)

The above is a small sample of the data. The real size of the first dataframe is 228x23. And the same goes to the second dataframe.
When I apply the add() to large dataframes how do I check that the output of the add() is correct? How do I make sure that each row in each column of the second dataframe has been added to each row in each column of the first dataframe of large dataframes?

Are the indexes of both DataFrames aligned/identical? What makes you believe that the result would not be correct?

@mozway The indexes of both DataFrame are aligned and identical. Extra step to make sure my calculations are correct, as I said both are large dataframe and I don't want there to be mistakes in my calculations

Are you aware that, for this example, the result is all NaN?

@wjandrea I did change the code to fill the NaN with zeros.

you would have to create other program which adds values and it compares result with total_returns. But this way you may go further - and you can create third program which checks if second program makes correct calculations, And later create fourth program which checks if third program makes correct calculations, etc. And all this makes no sense. You could also calculate it manually and put result in code and create code which compare it with total_returns but who will check if you made correct calculations.

or maybe you should choose randomly few elements and check them - and assume that the rest is also correct.
